# Is it possible that a change of the earth magnetic poles influences deep-sea currents?

Tags: oceanography, paleomagnetism

A deepwater circulation had changed direction about 55 million years ago, whereby salt cold water went from north to south. This was seen after research of foraminifera with carbon isotope change.
But where salt water consist of ions is it also possible that the change of the magnetic field of the earth could cause this change? Or are magnetic fields not of influence on salt water?

Comment: Could you include the reference to the research at least for the first part?

Comment: @aretxabaleta -- That would be the Palaeocene/Eocene Thermal Maximum, or PETM. A reference: Nunes, Flavia, and Richard D. Norris. "Abrupt reversal in ocean overturning during the Palaeocene/Eocene warm period." *Nature* 439.7072 (2006): 60-63. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Flavia_Nunes/publication/7375195_Abrupt_reversal_in_ocean_overturning_during_the_PalaeoceneEocene_warm_period/links/5460d6db0cf27487b4526192.pdf

Comment: I don't have the underlying reseach papers but it was concluded after research by oceanographers of the University of California in San Diego

Comment: That's correct is was about the PEMT